# How to make a proper cross join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to cross join the two table

Query

```
Select * from table1 cross join select * from table2
```

Above query is showing error.

What wrong in my query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Reference**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

The result set of the Cross Join is the number of rows in the first table multiplied by the number of rows in the second table

```
SELECT T1.Columns1, T1.Column2, T2.ColumnName FROM Table1 T1
CROSS JOIN Table2 t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2
```

or this:

```
select * from table1 CROSS JOIN table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use select like this : SELECT T1.FIELD1, T2.FIELD2 FROM TABLE1 AS T1 CROSS JOIN TABLE2 AS T2 - FIELD[X] FOR EXAMPLE ONLY